# Ubuntu 20.04 hotspot connection not resolving DNS for iPhone device

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq, wifi-hotspot

I have a wired connection on Ubuntu 20.04. I create a Hotspot connection. I believe NetworkManager automatically creates the following for my wireless interface:

```
inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
```

I want to connect to the Hotspot connection with my iPhone. This is what i set up on my iPhone manually:

```
IP Address: 192.168.0.11
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
Router: 10.42.0.1
```

I assume that I have to set the IP of the wireless interface as the router, because the Hotspot connction will be acting as the router in a sense. Is this correct? Where I have `Router: 10.42.0.1`

I am able to connect to the Hotspot, however upon examination of the traffic in Wireshark, it seems that the DNS is not resolving. The DNS settings on my iPhone are pointed to Google resolvers `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. I am seeing DNS queries to Google resolvers, however no response is coming back.

It also seems like when i created the Hotspot connection NetworkManager magically started `dnsmasq` as the local-resolver on the wireless interface. This is what `netstat -tupln` looks like:

```
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      148021/dnsmasq      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      147835/systemd-reso 
udp        0      0 10.42.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           148021/dnsmasq      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           147835/systemd-reso 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           148021/dnsmasq
```

I am not really sure what to do, I have tried disabling `ufw` as well in case it was a firewall issue. Still no luck. I have also tried setting the `ipv4.addresses` and `ipv4.dns` manually in `nmcli` instead of shared. Still nothing. Please let me know what I'm missing here. Been at this all day.

Comment: Can your phone reach any internet address via this router? Perhaps you forgot to enable IP forwarding. I am unsure where your dnsmasq process comes from and if that is related to your connectivity problem. Also, how exactly did you set up the hotspot?

Comment: If I connect my phone directly to the actual router then yes, it works normally. It just doesn't work if i use the Hotspot. I set up the Hotspot from the GUI (gnome-control-center) I was hoping it would work in a zero config manner. Although I tried setting it up through nmcli as well. Same problem. Do I have to enable IP forwarding for hotspot connection to work?

Comment: By "actual router", do you mean something else than the Ubuntu system? Or do you mean that access to any IP via Ubuntu fails? You don't have to enable ip forwarding for the hotspot to accept connections, but to forward traffic, because by default the Linux kernel ignores packets that are not destined to itself. I don't know whether IP forwarding is configured automatically by the Gnome control center. You may want to check the Network Manager configuration, `nmcli dev` or WiFi. I would guess that `hostapd` is used to implement the hotspot; it must log something somewhere.

Comment: yes I mean my actual mode/router gateway. The ubuntu Machine has a wired connection from the "actual" router and creates the hotspot for the phone/other devices. the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is `1`. I think it should be good ...

Answer (score 0):

#### BE CAREFUL WITH THE FIREWALL

**First try:**

```
sudo ufw disable
```

**If this solves the problem, you can do:**

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw       allow in  on wlo1
sudo ufw route allow out on enp41s0
```

**My system works with:** 
`sudo ufw status numbered`

```
[ 1] Anywhere on wlo1           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] Anywhere on enp41s0        ALLOW FWD   Anywhere       (out)
[ 3] Anywhere (v6) on wlo1      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 4] Anywhere (v6) on enp41s0   ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)  (out)
```

Only [ 1] and [ 2] are strictly necessary.

Knowing all of this before would help me a lot!